# use == to check if two objects have the same value or not in python

Tags: python

The following is the code:

```
class foo:
   def __init__(self,p1,p2):
       self.a1 = p1
       self.a2 = p2

def main():
    o1=foo("lucy","jack")
    o2=foo('lucy','jack')
    print(o1==o2)
main()
```

I understand that o1 and o2 are different objects. What confuses me is that, they have the same value, right? And the "==" is used to check to see if two objects have the same value or not, right? Did I miss something here?

Comment: You forgot to define `__eq__()`.

Comment: You haven't defined what "the same value" means for your objects.

Comment: Python has [very good documentation](https://docs.python.org/). I suggest you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define equal objects as objects with all the same instance variables, this is easier then writing code to test each variable:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        self.a1 = p1
        self.a2 = p2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__


def main():
    o1=foo("lucy","jack")
    o2=foo('lucy','jack')
    print(o1==o2)
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your custom `__eq__`:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        self.a1 = p1
        self.a2 = p2

    def __eq__(self, another):
        return self.a1 == another.a1 and self.a2 == another.a2   

def main():
    o1=foo("lucy","jack")
    o2=foo('lucy','jack')
    print(o1==o2)
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

When python doesn't know how to compare objects - it checks to see if you're handling the same instance. This is the same as what the `is` operator does.

If you want to override how python compares object - you will need to define the `__eq__` method in your class.

See the [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) for more information